# Accessing values from a dictionary using a list of lists and returning a list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary called dict which looks like this:

```
{1: [0, 1], 2: [2, 3], 3: [4], 4: [5, 6, 7, 8], 5: [9, 10], 7: [11, 12], 8: [13, 14, 15], 9: [16], 10: [17], 11: [18], 13: [19], 14: [20], 15: [21], 17: [22], 18: [23, 24], 19: [25], 21: [26, 27, 28], 22: [29], 24: [30, 31, 32], 25: [33, 34], 27: [35], 28: [36], 31: [37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42], 32: [43, 44, 45, 46, 47], 34: [48, 49, 50, 51, 52], 35: [53, 54, 55, 56], 36: [57, 58, 59], 37: [60], 40: [61, 62], 41: [63, 64, 65, 66], 43: [67], 44: [68, 69], 45: [70, 71], 48: [72, 73, 74], 49: [75, 76], 51: [77], 52: [78, 79], 53: [80, 81], 54: [82], 55: [83], 58: [84, 85, 86], 59: [87], 61: [88, 89], 62: [90], 63: [91], 64: [92, 93], 65: [94], 68: [95], 69: [96], 71: [97], 73: [98, 99], 74: [100], 76: [101], 77: [102]}
```

I have a list called remainID which looks like this:

```
[[13, 24, 62, 69, 34, 31], [44, 11, 2, 55, 22, 53], [59, 40, 3, 54, 32, 71], [15, 64, 73, 5, 10], [68, 61, 9, 18, 48], [41, 58, 65, 1, 27], [37, 7, 51, 35, 25], [17, 74, 63, 8, 36]]
```

remainID contains a list of lists which are all the values of the keys in the dictionary. I would like to change all the keys values in remainID to the dictionary value pair of the key. This would mean that instead of having a list that has multiple lists of the keys in dict, I would like a list that has multiple lists of the values in the dict. However, the number of lists in remainID cannot change but the length of each list might be different. How do I do this?

For example, consider the first list in remainID: 
`[13, 24, 62, 69, 34, 31]`

This list should become:
`[19, 30, 31, 32,  90,  48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42]`

Comment: can you share the sample o/p you are looking for, i see too many statements. Take a sample set and please explain

Comment: It's unclear. Can you give the expected O/P ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following list comprehension (assuming your dictionary is named `d` since you shouldn't name it `dict` as it shadows the built-in class):

```
remainID = [[s for i in l for s in d[i]] for l in remainID]
```

`remainID` would become:

`[[19, 30, 31, 32, 90, 96, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42], [68, 69, 18, 2, 3, 83, 29, 80, 81], [87, 61, 62, 4, 82, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 97], [21, 92, 93, 98, 99, 9, 10, 17], [95, 88, 89, 16, 23, 24, 72, 73, 74], [63, 64, 65, 66, 84, 85, 86, 94, 0, 1, 35], [60, 11, 12, 77, 53, 54, 55, 56, 33, 34], [22, 100, 91, 13, 14, 15, 57, 58, 59]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `list comprehension` + `itertools`,

```
from itertools import chain
remain_id = [list(chain.from_iterable([d.get(j) for j in i])) for i in remain_id]
```

Result:

```
Out[78]: 
[[19, 30, 31, 32, 90, 96, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42],
 [68, 69, 18, 2, 3, 83, 29, 80, 81],
 [87, 61, 62, 4, 82, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 97],
 [21, 92, 93, 98, 99, 9, 10, 17],
 [95, 88, 89, 16, 23, 24, 72, 73, 74],
 [63, 64, 65, 66, 84, 85, 86, 94, 0, 1, 35],
 [60, 11, 12, 77, 53, 54, 55, 56, 33, 34],
 [22, 100, 91, 13, 14, 15, 57, 58, 59]]
```